# Changing data type of 'createdAt' and 'updatedAt' fields in Sequelize model to DATE(6)

Tags: mysql, node.js, date, sequelize.js, database-migration

Sequelize automatically adds a `createdAt` and a `updatedAt` field for every model, both of which are set to type `DATE` by  default. I want to update this to `DATE(6)` to be able to make use of millisecond timestamps. I have two questions regarding this:

1. How do I go about creating a migration that enables this?
2. If I update the datatype to `DATE(6)`, will the existing database records be unaffected and will only the newer ones have the millisecond timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

1- The migration required to effect this change (presuming a `cards` table):

```py
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return Promise.all([
            // cards
            queryInterface.changeColumn('cards', 'createdAt', {
                type: Sequelize.DATE(6),
                allowNull: true,
            }),
            queryInterface.changeColumn('cards', 'updatedAt', {
                type: Sequelize.DATE(6),
                allowNull: true,
            }),
        ])
    },

    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return Promise.all([
            // cards
            queryInterface.changeColumn('cards', 'createdAt', {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                allowNull: true,
            }),
            queryInterface.changeColumn('cards', 'updatedAt', {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                allowNull: true,
            }),
        ])
    }
};
```

2- The preceding migration runs an `ALTER TABLE` query on the `cards` table and all rows (previous ones and those that are yet to be inserted) will get the millisecond timestamp.